# Trying to Change Icon of Button When Clicked

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

First here is my Plunker code: http://plnkr.co/edit/NAH3ePyZdQePbB9EdOzW?p=preview

I'm trying to change the icon from icon-refresh to icon-spinner when the button is clicked but for some reason it's not working. I am pretty new to HTML so I believe there might be a syntax error somewhere but I'm stumped.

Comment: Works fine [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/W8svDNFaIY4kDAYvMaIl?p=preview)

Comment: I apologize. I just edited my question. What I'm trying to do is change it when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your document.getElementById("something").innerText = "Loading..."; command is replacing all the contents of the  tag, including the i tag. You can wrap your text in a span and then target the innerText of the span:

```
<a href='#' onclick="load()" id="something" class="buttonLink">
      <i id="changeThis" class="icon-refresh"></i> <span id="button-text">Button</span>
</a>
```

javascript:

```
document.getElementById("button-text").innerText = "Loading...";
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you. Now I just gotta get my head wrapped around why this works.

Comment: Your original javascript: document.getElementById("something").innerText = "Loading..."; was completely changing the contents of the a#something and replacing them with "Loading...". This includes the i tag, so you were removing the i tag completely from inside the a tag.